# How might i turn M_PI into an integer vector. So basically 3.14159... into {3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9...}

Tags: vector

I have been trying to do this for so long but cannot figure it out for the life of me. I am extremely new to c++. I just started learning it less than 4 months ago. But i cannot figure it out on my own

Comment: Find a good reference for C++and dig out a function which takes the integer part of a floating-point number, ie which takes input `3.14159...` and returns `3`.  Find another function which returns the fraction, ie `.14159...`..  Multiply that by `10`, take the integer part, multiply the fraction by `10`, take the integer part ... you get the idea

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.